# What's the name of this type of View Presentation Style?

Tags: ios, view, presentation-model

[image]

What's the name of this type of view and how do I implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [UIModalPresentationStyleFormSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIModalPresentationFormSheet)

Comment: THANKS! Exactly what I wanted.